# Dart FFI lookup/asFunction does not accept generic type that extends NativeType

Tags: dart, generics, dart-ffi

This code snippet defines a generic function that has a type parameter `T extends NativeType`. Then `T` is used to define a C function signature to look up symbols from a dynamic library.

```dart
import 'dart:ffi';

lookupGeneric<T extends NativeType>() {
  final dylib = DynamicLibrary.open("path");
  final address = dylib.lookup<NativeFunction<Void Function(Pointer<T>)>>("Name");
  final function = address.asFunction<void Function(Pointer<T>)>(isLeaf: false);
  return (address, function);
}

void main() {
  final func = lookupGeneric<Int8>();
}
```

My issue is that this code fails to compile with the following message:

```
Can't invoke 'asFunction' because the function signature 'NativeFunction<Void Function(Pointer<T>)>' for the pointer isn't a valid C function signature.
```

When I replace `T` for plain `NativeType`, it compiles without errors:

```dart
import 'dart:ffi';

lookupGeneric<T extends NativeType>() {
  final dylib = DynamicLibrary.open("path");
  //                                                 -> CHANGE HERE ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ
  final address = dylib.lookup<NativeFunction<Void Function(Pointer<NativeType>)>>("Name");
  final function = address.asFunction<void Function(Pointer<T>)>(isLeaf: false);
  return (address, function);
}

void main() {
  final func = lookupGeneric<Int8>();
}
```

I don't, however, find this a satisfactory solution, and it also doesn't work when `T` is not used as a pointer.

Can someone explain why `NativeType` works but `T extends NativeType` doesn't? What would be the solution to use generic types in `dart:ffi`?